# Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). When I use official latex documents, it report this。

Tags: spacing, packages

When I use the original template of BMVC(one of famous computer science conference), it report this problem. But other one can work it. So i am very curious where some place I install mactex incorrect.
The more stranges is this file work

```
\documentclass{bmvc2k}

%% Enter your paper number here for the review copy
\bmvcreviewcopy{??}

\title{Author Guidelines for the\\ British Machine Vision Conference}

% Enter the paper's authors in order
% \addauthor{Name}{email/homepage}{INSTITUTION_CODE}
\addauthor{Susan Student}{http://www.vision.inst.ac.uk/~ss}{1}
\addauthor{Petra Prof}{http://www.vision.inst.ac.uk/~pp}{1}
\addauthor{Colin Collaborator}{colin@collaborators.com}{2}

% Enter the institutions
% \addinstitution{Name\\Address}
\addinstitution{
 The Vision Institute\\
 University of Borsetshire\\
 Wimbleham, UK
}
\addinstitution{
 Collaborators, Inc.\\
 123 Park Avenue,\\
 New York, USA
}

\runninghead{Student, Prof, Collaborator}{BMVC Author Guidelines}

% Any macro definitions you would like to include
% These are not defined in the style file, because they don't begin
% with \bmva, so they might conflict with the user's own macros.
% The \bmvaOneDot macro adds a full stop unless there is one in the
% text already.
\def\eg{\emph{e.g}\bmvaOneDot}
\def\Eg{\emph{E.g}\bmvaOneDot}
\def\etal{\emph{et al}\bmvaOneDot}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Document starts here
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
abc  and to print well at one or two pages per sheet.
Additional features include: pop-up annotations for
citations~\cite{Authors06,Mermin89}; a margin ruler for reviewing; and a
greatly simplified way of entering multiple authors and institutions.

{\bf All authors are encouraged to read this document}, even if you have
written many papers before.  As well as a description of the format, the
document contains many instructions relating to formatting problems and
errors that are common even in the work of authors who {\em have}
written many papers before.
\end{abstract}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}
\LaTeX\ users should use this template in order to prepare their paper.
Users of other packages should emulate the style and layout of this
example.  Note that best results will be achieved using {\tt pdflatex},
which is available in most modern distributions.

\subsection{Paper length}
Papers must be 9~pages in length, {\em excluding} the bibliography.
%Length is counted from the bottom of the title on the first page.  Therefore, the
%bibliography should begin eight lines into page ten.  This is an
%approximate measure, intended to encourage brevity, but authors should keep
%in mind that blatant disregard of this instruction will cause reviewers to
%require greater originality and impact of the submission.
{\bf Papers which are
clearly overlength will not be reviewed}.  This includes papers where the
margins and formatting are deemed to have been significantly altered from
those laid down by this style guide.  The reason such papers will not be
reviewed is that there is no provision for supervised revisions of
manuscripts.  The reviewing process cannot determine the suitability of the
paper for presentation in nine pages if it is reviewed in twelve.

The bibliography should begin immediately after the paper text.  It may
be of any length, within reason.  It should {\em not} include
annotations, figures, or any other paraphernalia intended to subvert the
paper length requirement.

\subsection{Dual submission} 
By submitting this manuscript to BMVC, the authors assert that it has not
been previously published in substantially similar form, and no paper
currently under submission to a conference contains significant overlap
with this one.  If you are in doubt about the amount of overlap, cite the
dual submission (as described below), and argue in the body of your paper
why this is a nontrivial advance.  a simultaneous journal submission would
be expected to have significant additional material not in the conference
paper, and should not be previously published, nor in the final acceptance
zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz
zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz 
\end{document}
```

the error is

```
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \kern 
l.94 \end{document}

?
```

but when I add more line, it report this problem, so strange! anyone can help me

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question to add the following: the exact text of the error you get; a link to somewhere we can find the class you are using. But you certainly need an `\end{document}` at the end.

Comment: Please fix your question so that the example generates the error you ask about. The class file and package are available from https://github.com/timm/BMVC but as posted the example generates no error OK I can reproduce, I'll edit.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually this is from https://bmvc2017.london/paper-submission/. there is template.  Some others can work it very well, but i get the problem when I use mac. I guess it is because the mactex I used to install different version. The templates can work well in other machine, but in my machine, it crapted. Besides,  Other conference template. i can work well. so strange!

Comment: No it is not related to mac or anything in the tex distribution, it is simply that file both where I found it originally and at the bmvc2017 link you give is broken. It will give the error you report on any file more than one page long. There is nothing strange or subtle in the error it is simply a class file that does not work. You should report it to the conference organisers.

Answer (score 4):

Line 653 of the class as retrieved from

https://github.com/timm/BMVC

has

```
\put(\LenToUnit{\textwidth\kern3pt}
```

it is a bit hard to guess the intent of that kern, but it is clearly a syntax error

Changing the line to

```
    \put(\LenToUnit{\textwidth},\LenToUnit{-\bmv@ruleroffset}){%right ruler
```

allows the file to run without error.

You should report this to the class maintainer.

Comment: Great, it works. Thanks, regards. I spend one day it not works, thanks for your anwsering.